# Make media loop many times with direct show c++

Tags: c++, mp3, directshow, multimedia

I am using direct show to play media files within my program, and i have been able to play a media file a single time using the following code.

```
void main()
{
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
    }

    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(L"C:\\Example.mp3", NULL);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pControl->Run();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);
        }
    }

    pControl->Release();
    pEvent->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
}
```

My question then becomes how would i make the file continue to play and repeat itself a given number of times, or infinitely if i so desired.  IMediaControl has no member named loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this. Once way of implementing this is that instead of exiting you function when you get the completion event, you seek to the beginning of the file an start playback again. 
The following link on event handling may help: [Learning When an Event Occurs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `EC_COMPLETE` event/notification is issued when streaming is complete.